# Splitting XML into multiple files with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around XSLT but I heard it's possible to split an XML file into multiple files. Basically I'd like to copy all the elements up to the first file and after the last file and then add the individual file content for each output file.

Could someone give me some pointers on this if it's even possible?

Thanks,

**complete.xml**

```
<rootelem>
  <elem>
    <file attr1='1'>
      <content>content file 1</content>
    </file>
    <file attr2='2'>
      <content>content file 2</content>
    </file>
    <file attr3='3'>
      <content>content file 3</content>
    </file>
  </elem>
</rootelem>
```

**OUTPUT:**

**complete_PART1.xml**

```
<rootelem>
  <elem>
     <file attr1='1'>
        <content>content file 1</content>
     </file>
  </elem>
</rootelem>
```

**complete_PART2.xml**

```
<rootelem>
  <elem>
    <file attr2='2'>
      <content>content file 2</content>
    </file>
  </elem>
</rootelem>
```

**complete_PART3.xml**

```
<rootelem>
  <elem>
     <file attr3='3'>
        <content>content file 3</content>
     </file>
  </elem>
</rootelem>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for directions about the standard support of XSLT (1.0 and 2.0) of producing multiplr output results.

Comment: I have a requirement to split large XML files into smaller files, but I was going to write a program to do (it needs to poll a folder and process files over x megs big) - there's loads of different file types - e.g. I don't know the XML structure up front so I need a generic splitter - can this be done with XSLT or should I use the .NET XML reading tools?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Responding to your comment on @Dimitre's answer...

You wrote,

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="elem/file">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This doesn't quite match your XML, which has `rootelem` as an outermost element, and your comment says `root` as an outermost element. You probably want something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:for-each select="elem/file">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml">
      <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/root/@*" />
        <elem>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | ." />
        </elem>
      </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You could get fancier, trying to use `<xsl:copy>` instead of literal result elements for root and elem, but it doesn't seem worth the effort unless they're going to vary.

Comment: You're right Lars, sorry sloppy copying from the actual file. I did something similar to what you have but the problem is that root and elem have various attributes that i need to maintain. But maybe I can somehow use the parent <xsl:copy-of select=".."> still trying to wrap my head around xslt.

Comment: @Nisse, I edited the answer to preserve the attributes of root and elem. The trouble with xsl:copy-of is that you can't modify the parts of what gets copied... you just copy the whole tree(s) under the node(s) you select. You can't add or omit anything. So you can't xsl:copy-of /root or /root/elem. But if you xsl:copy-of the needed attributes you're in good shape.

Answer (score 16):

**It is not possible in pure XSLT 1.0** to produce more than one output files. One could use the **[`<exslt:document>`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** extension element for this purpose.

**In XSLT 2.0 use the [`<xsl:result-document>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-result-document) element.**

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks for your reply. I'm using xsl:result-document now and it splits the file but puts <file> as the top level element. However, I want to keep <root> and <elem> in each of the generated files. Any suggestions on that?    <xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:for-each select="elem/file"> <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml"> <xsl:copy-of select="."/> </xsl:result-document> </xsl:for-each> </xsl:template>

Comment: may i know how to configure <exslt:document> extension in VS2010 professional.

Comment: @Jeevan: One (the only I know) way to achieve this is to install EXSLT-MVP -- see this announcement by Oleg Tkachenko: http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000293.html

Comment: `<exslt:document>` worked great for me. In case it helps others: I had to include `extension-element-prefixes="exslt"` in the root node before it'd work as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use

```
<xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml">
```

from an ANT xslt call, you need to use 2.0., just add the following in your ANT call:

```
<classpath location="/home/ap/saxon/saxon8.jar" />
```

And specifiy Version="2.0"
And enjoy file splitting.

Comment: @millebbi: Sorry, but maybe this should go in another question actually asking about ant integration with Saxon XSLT processor...

Comment: Well it would go in both, because I also wanted to use :  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml">, however ANT is by default using 1.0, with adding this ANT statement you can use <xsl:result-document>