# xslt create a new xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xsl_style.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tableStyle" >
      <table id="products_table">
      <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#B5E4EA">
          <td>A/A</td>
          <td>Product Name</td>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>Corpration</td>
          <td>Category</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:variable name="allProducts" select="auction_products/product" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$allProducts">
          <xsl:sort select="category"/>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$allProducts[$pos]/count_products"/></td>
            <td><a href="offer.php"><xsl:value-of select="product_name"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="offer.php"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="offer.php"><xsl:value-of select="corporation"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="offer.php"><xsl:value-of select="category"/></a></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and i want to create a new xml file through xslt with the sorted data.Is impossible to do that in xslt version 1? I tried the `xsl:document` but i didn't make it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036233/splitting-xml-into-multiple-files-with-xslt

Comment: I try that solution but didn't work..i don't want to do it with xslt version 2.

Comment: XSLT processors do not change because you "want" something. As Dimitre said, this cannot be done in pure XSLT 1.0 - only using EXSLT or XSLT 2.0 (`result-document`).

Comment: If i need to do it with result-document of xslt version 2, what changes must do to my xslt file?Thanks for your advise..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to output several documents from within the same XSLT (1.0) stylesheet.

As this link: [Splitting XML into multiple files with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036233/splitting-xml-into-multiple-files-with-xslt) suggests, this is not possible with the means provided in XSLT 1.0. Either you extend your XSLT 1.0 setup with EXSLT (http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) or you use XSLT 2.0 instead.

If you decide to use XSLT 2.0, you obviously need to change the version info to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
```

Then, incorporate `result-document` into your stylesheet. I suggest you look for appropriate information on the web, e.g. here: http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/xsl-elements/result-document.html.

Note that you'll also need a processor that is capable of `XSLT 2.0`, like Saxon. And while you ponder on this, also think about whether it is strictly necessary to have one stylesheet output several files and why.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i found another way to to it.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this with XSLT 1.0- one is to simply embed the sorted data into the output html, and it should be a relatively simply matter to extract the data you need from it.

The other is to use xsl:message to output the data you want as messages, and implement a mechanism for recording that output.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i found another way to to it