# how to call JBOSS service from stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, powershell, jboss

I have a project where I need to send an email from JBOSS 6.  I'm hoping that I can do it from a stylesheet.  Is there a way to call the 'sendmail' service in JBOSS 6 from XSL?  I'm just not sure if its possible or even how to do it.  If its not possible, maybe I can have the stylesheet output some text into a file somewhere for powershell to watch and send mail from it?

EDIT:  I have added code

Here is some code that I am trying to make generate a ".txt" file, but it is not being generated.  There are no errors that I can see from the transformer.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:variable name="emailPID" select="attr[@tag='00100020']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="emailPName" select="attr[@tag='00100010']"/>
  <!-- overwritten by application with actual values -->
  <xsl:param name="calling" select="'SAMPLE_MOD'"/>
  <xsl:param name="called" select="'SERVER1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="date" select="'20051206'"/>
  <xsl:param name="time" select="'115600.000'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/dataset">
    <exsl:document href="c:\apps\foo.txt">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$emailPID"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$emailPName"/>
    </exsl:document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT can output text content to a file. But you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: then I might go that way.  I just need to send a simple email and I can use windows powershell to look at a text file to generate an email.  If my stylesheet is using XSLT1 can I use 'TWO' output methods in one file?  One doing "method="xml"" for my applications' function and the other doing  "method="text"" to generate a text file?

Comment: I may just need to ask a new question instead :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If my stylesheet is using XSLT1 can I use 'TWO' output methods in one file? One doing "method="xml"" for my applications' function and the other doing "method="text"" to generate a text file?

No, with pure XSLT 1.0 it is not possible to produce multiple output files.

You could use an extension function from EXSLT, see Dimitre Novatchev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036522/1987598). Another solution to your problem is to write two separate XSLT stylesheets, one producing "text" output, the other "xml".

Moreover, the `method` attribut of the `xsl:output` element is unique and there cannot be both "xml" and "text" in an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet.

If you use XSLT 2.0, however, this functionality is covered by the `xsl:result-document` element. This element can be used multiple times and also has a `method` attribute.