# Splitting XML with a common head node and several bodies node into multiple files with XSLT

Tags: xml, file, xslt, split, transformation

I have an XML document, structured like the following example:

```
<p:Document versione="1.0"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DocumentHeader>
     global header
  </DocumentHeader>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 1
  </DocumentBody>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 2
  </DocumentBody>
</p:Document>
```

Note that "global header" and "body X" may rappresent nested xml-blocks, not just plain text.

and I need to split this XML file into - in this example - two XML files, like the followings:

```
<p:Document versione="1.0"    
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DocumentHeader>
     global header
  </DocumentHeader>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 1
  </DocumentBody>
</p:Document>
```

and

```
<p:Document versione="1.0"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DocumentHeader>
     global header
  </DocumentHeader>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 2
  </DocumentBody>
</p:Document>
```

Generally, I have to create several new XML, one for each DocumentBody node, putting the same DocumentHeader node in each new file created.

I think an XSL transformation is the best way to do this, but I dont know how.
I've tried to use the example reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036233/splitting-xml-into-multiple-files-with-xslt?rq=1), but these cases don't manage an "header" node.

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:for-each select="DocumentBody">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@id}-output.xml">
      <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/root/@*" />
        <DocumentBody>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | ." />
        </DocumentBody>
      </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Can you help me?

---

Update after receiving first answer.
I execute the transformation via Saxon tools, using the suggested code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
            xmlns:p="http://example.com/p">
  <xsl:template match="/p:Document">
    <xsl:for-each select="DocumentBody">
      <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{position()}-output.xml">
        <p:Document>
          <xsl:copy-of select="/*/@*, ../DocumentHeader, ." />
        </p:Document>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I note the following difference between the original xml and one of the new documents.
Original (part of):

```
<p:Document versione="1.0" 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DocumentHeader>
```

File 1 (part of):

```
<p:Document
xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" versione="1.0">
<DocumentHeader 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Maybe I need a difference espression in this select?

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/@*, ../DocumentHeader, ." />
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your real example, is there an actual `id` attribute on the `DocumentBody` elements or is that just something you copied from the example you're working from?  If not, how do you propose to generate the output file names, would sequential numbers be sufficient?

Comment: Also, can we assume your real XML is properly namespace-well-formed (i.e. the `p:` prefix is properly declared on the root `Document` element)?  If it isn't then you can't process it using XSLT.

Comment: @Ian, the xslt code is just a work-in-progress example. I mean, there is no `id` attribute in my original xml document. The generated output file name can be a sequential numbers.

Comment: @IanRoberts, the XML is well formed, I mean, he respect the format I should use in my application. For more details, I just simplify this [document](http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0/IT01234567890_33333.xml), that's the "elettronic invoice" of Italian Governament. The schema is available [here](http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.1.xsd)

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your example XML to be namespace-well-formed:

```
<p:Document versione="1.0" xmlns:p="http://example.com/p">
  <DocumentHeader>
     global header
  </DocumentHeader>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 1
  </DocumentBody>
  <DocumentBody>
     body 2
  </DocumentBody>
</p:Document>
```

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet should do what you require:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:p="http://example.com/p">
  <xsl:template match="/p:Document">
    <xsl:for-each select="DocumentBody">
      <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{position()}-output.xml">
        <p:Document>
          <xsl:copy-of select="/*/@*, ../DocumentHeader, ." />
        </p:Document>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `copy-of` copies three things to the result document - the attributes of the original root element, the `DocumentHeader`, and the current `DocumentBody`.  As written this assumes that the DocumentHeader and DocumentBody elements are not in a namespace, if they are then you'll need to declare it in the stylesheet with a suitable prefix and adapt the XPath expressions accordingly.

In this context the `position()` function gives you a number that is essentially the "iteration counter" for the `for-each` - 1 for the first `DocumentBody`, 2 for the second, etc.

Comment: I add your solution into the question, saying that applying it the result is unexpect (sure because I miss to include the namespace and other things). Hope that now the question is really complete

Answer (score 0):

The following transformation - strongly based on @IanRoberts's one - should finally solve the question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/p:Document">
    <xsl:for-each select="DocumentBody">
      <xsl:result-document method="xml" 
        href="{substring-before(base-uri(),'.xml')}_doc_n°_{position()}.xml">
        <p:Document versione="1.0" 
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
            xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/@*, ../DocumentHeader, ." />
        </p:Document>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Suppose the original xml is named example.xml, the name of the new files are "example_doc_n°1.xml" etc. 
Note: For people interested in italian elettronic invoice, called "Fattura Elettronica", please replace Document with FatturaElettronica.