# SaxonHE 9 to create multiple files with XSLT from a very large file

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm using the information from [Splitting XML into multiple files with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036233/splitting-xml-into-multiple-files-with-xslt) to split an XML file that's 143M in size. If I manually take a handful of records out of the file, the following template works as suggested from the above link.

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Report_Entry">
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="record-{position()}.xml">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

My problem seems to be when I apply the XSLT to the larger document, which doesn't create the files, and outputs only the xml header when no output is provided when the files are created.

```
$ java -Xmx512M -jar /usr/local/bin/saxon9he.jar largefile.xml transform.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I'm working in Cygwin and using 32 bit Java v1.7.0_55.

Adding the `-t` option results in the following output:

```
Saxon-HE 9.6.0.5J from Saxonica
Java version 1.7.0_55
Stylesheet compilation time: 609.975948ms
Processing file:/C:/Users/username/Documents/Projects/xml/largefile.xml
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:/C:/Users/username/Documents/Projects/largefile.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 5.85596s (5855.960358ms)
Tree size: 6942834 nodes, 55451426 characters, 0 attributes
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Execution time: 5.913265s (5913.265026ms)
Memory used: 402449896
NamePool contents: 40 entries in 37 chains. 8 URIs
```

Is the file just too large for the HE version of Saxon? Is there some other setting or reason that I'm getting output, rather than a collection of files?

Comment: Try the `-t` command line option with Saxon to see whether it outputs any messages telling you why creating files failed.

Comment: Thanks. I've added `-t`. It doesn't look like it provides much in this case.

Comment: Well in that case I assume the path `Report_Data/Report_Entry` does not select anything in the input document. The main reason for that is usually a namespace e.g. `<Report_Data xmlns="http://example.com/"><Report_Entry>...</Report_Entry></Report_Data>`. Can you show us a few lines of the real input?

Comment: That was it! Namespace was mismatched! Post it as the answer, and I'll be sure to confirm it!

Comment: I have written an answer so you can accept it and the question will be shown as solved.

Comment: @jktravis If you split purely because "the file is too large or takes too long to load", might I suggest considering the switch from a DOM parser to a SAX parser. Maybe you're solving the wrong problem with the file split.

Comment: Thanks @tomalak. The problem is that I have an XML report of resumes that need to be split into individual XML files for each entry/person. The end point that will consume these files will index them to make them searchable. For whatever reason, this endpoint cannot parse the XML itself, update a database, or do anything fancy with the data besides just index the file(s). They need to be individual files since the one big file would return on every match because its one big file. Not a very good solution, for sure, but here I am. =/

Comment: No, that's a perfectly valid reason for splitting the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no files created and you don't get any out of memory error message then I assume your path `Report_Data/Report_Entry` does not select anything, the main reason for that is usually a namespace declaration in the input file, e.g. `<Report_Data xmlns="http://example.com/"><Report_Entry>...</Report_Entry></Report_Data>`. The easiest fix in XSLT 2.0 is to put `xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element, then you don't need to change any paths in the stylesheet code you have posted.